# Robolectric Test AndroidManifest propeperties

Tags: manifest, robolectric

Anyone has a example how to access the AndroidManifest.xml to test that several properties are set ?

For Example i would like to test that an Activity has a Action as intent filter set.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you browse Robolectric's [source](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric), and specifically `[master]/src/test/java/org/robolectric/AndroidManifestTest.java`, you will find inspiration. They've done a pretty good job in thorougly testing the xml.